# SDL_PollEvent sometime not capturing touch event after screen reconnect

Tags: c++, sdl-2, touchscreen

I am using SDL libarary for capturing touch and mouse event on screen. But if i disconnect touch screen and reconnect it, Sometime i stop getting finger touch events i.e SDL_FINGERMOTION, SDL_FINGERDOWN, SDL_FINGERUP.

Below is the code i am using:

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:{
                //Some Code
            }
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:{
                //Some Code
            }
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:{
                //Some Code
            }
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:{
               //Some Code
            }
        case SDL_FINGERMOTION:
        case SDL_FINGERDOWN:
        case SDL_FINGERUP: {
             //Some Code
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

P.S using opensuse 42.2 and SDL2

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, SDL opens each available input event device the moment you call `SDL_Init(... | SDL_INIT_EVENTS)`. If an input device is removed from the system, SDL will get an error whenever it tries to poll it. However, SDL does not get a notification when a new input device is added, and so it will never open new input event devices.

A workaround might be to periodically check `/dev/input/event*` yourself, see if anything has changed, and if so, do `SDL_QuitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_EVENTS); SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVENTS)`. However, that is a hack, and might not work reliably.

Comment: More-or-less recent SDL2 supports hot add for joysticks, gamepads, audio devices, and on some implementations (e.g. linux evdev) touchscreens.

Comment: @G. Sliepen I dont see SDL_Exit in SDL do you mean SDL_QuitSubSystem ?

Comment: Unfortunatelyits not working. I have added below on reconnect event in my application  SDL_QuitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_EVENTS);
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVENTS)

Comment: Ah, yes, I meant `SDL_QuitSubSystem()`.

Comment: After investigating SDL2 lib, i found that sometime after re connection, touch id of touch device get change, and  because of that SDL could not process touch events as it has different mapping of touch id and touch device which was created initially with SDL_Init. So we have to call SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) to re initialize SDL touch id and touch device mapping. Unfortunately my project does not allow to re initialize the SDL again. So i have to get touch id using X11 api's to deal with this problem.